# In R, how to turn character to verbatim expression?

Tags: r, metaprogramming, non-standard-evaluation

If I do this:

```
parse(text="foo()")
```

I get:

`expression(foo())`

But what I really need is:

`foo()`

So basically `"foo()"` -> `foo()`

Also, if I try:

```
as.symbol("foo()")
```

I get:

```
`foo()`
```

I don't want the tick marks

Comment: Try `eval(as.symbol("foo"))`.

Comment: You can try 'get' function or 'eval' to work with parse output. I am not sure do u want to print the function without quotes or evaluate something which is under quotes? Use noquote function on strings to print without quotes. Or print with quote= FALSE

Comment: First, you shouldn't use parse like this. Using parse is not proper meta-programming. Then: parse(text="foo()")[[1]] gives you the call.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Evaluate function? (I think not looking at your comments) Print name? But where? To file, to console? What problem you want to solve? `cat("foo()")` writes `foo()` to console, but it is just printing things.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
foo <- function(x) pi*x
eval(as.symbol("foo"))(1:10)
#[1]  3.141593  6.283185  9.424778 12.566371 15.707963 18.849556 21.991149
#[8] 25.132741 28.274334 31.415927
```

The return value of `eval(.)` can be assigned to an object and it will be a function.

```
f <- eval(as.symbol("foo"))
f
#function(x) pi*x

f(2)
#[1] 6.283185
```

Comment: I do not want to evaluate the expression. I just want the expression without the tick marks.

Answer (score 0):

```
parse(text="foo()") %>% as.character %>% noquote
[1] foo()
```